# Google Sheets - How do I prevent negative values when simulating data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula, simulate

**Background Info**

- I have a maximum of 15 hours available for work Monday – Friday.
- Each day, from Monday – Thursday, I will work a random amount of
  hours between 0 – 8.
- I can work 0 hours on Monday - Thursday.
- On Friday, I will work whatever hours are left from the maximum of 15
  hours available.
- I must work at least 1 hour on Friday.

**Formulas Used**

- (Cell: C4) Monday: RANDBETWEEN(0-8)
- (Cell: D4) Tuesday: RANDBETWEEN(0-8)
- (Cell: E4) Wednesday: RANDBETWEEN(0-8)
- (Cell: F4) Thursday: RANDBETWEEN(0-8)
- (Cell: G4) Friday: 15 – SUM(C4:F4)
- Total Hours: SUM(C4:G4)

**Issues**

- The Friday cell will occasionally receive a negative number of hours
  worked.

**Example Output of Issue**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnJWO.png)

**Current Workaround**

- Update the values generated by RANDBETWEEN by pressing ‘DEL’ on an
  empty cell. This forces all the values to change.

  Repeat until a positive value is received in the cell for Friday

[Google Sheet Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbINN.png)

**Goal**

Have the cells update themselves automatically **IF** a negative value is received in the cell for Friday

**Possible Solution/Thoughts**

Is there a way to force RANDBETWEEN numbers to update via a formula?

If yes, is there a way to setup a WHILE loop that will update the
RANDBETWEEN values UNTIL the cell for Friday has a positive number?

Is there a way to have a script run on specific cells? The intent is to simulate data for variations on a work schedule.

I did try to accomplish this via a script but wasn’t able to get the cells to update correctly and other times it would not update at all.

```
function randomTotal() 
{
  var Monday = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C4');
  var Tuesday = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D4');
  var Wednesday = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E4');
  var Thursday = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F4');
  var Friday = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G4');
  var FridayValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G4').getValue();
  
  while(FridayValue < 0)
  {
    newTotal(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday);
    FridayValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G4').getValue();
  }
}
```

```
function newTotal(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday)
{
  Monday.setFormula('=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)');
  Tuesday.setFormula('=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)');
  Wednesday.setFormula('=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)');
  Thursday.setFormula('=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)');
  Friday.setFormula('=15-SUM(C4:F4)');
}
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with this solution where there are still cases where failures (negatives) occur.

Example Failure Case:

RANDOM C4 = 8
RANDOM D4 = 8
=RANDBETWEEN(0,MIN(14-C4-D4,8))
=RANDBETWEEN(0,MIN(14-8-8,8))
=RANDBETWEEN(0,MIN(-2,8))
=RANDBETWEEN(0,-2)
-> FAILS DUE TO NEGATIVE #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can actually be accomplished without Google Apps Script. I would suggest the following formulas for cell D4

`=RANDBETWEEN(0,IF(SUM($C4:C4)<=6,8,14-SUM($C4:C4)))`

You can then copy/paste this from D4 into E4 and F4 (the formula references will work), and keep C4 and G4 as is. That should do the trick!

You absolutely can accomplish this programmatically, but in general, if it's possible to do without, that's usually the simpler approach.

For a quick explanation of why this works: if the cells to the left sum to <=6, then you can always add up to 8 hours, because it leaves you in the range of <= 14 total. But, if that's not the case, you want to subtract however many hours you already have from 14, as 14 is the max you can have on Mon - Thurs, and get the remaining of at least 1 on Friday.

Comment: I ran some numbers to do some verification of your solution.

The issue I ran into is I will now get a failure to run RANDBETWEEN due to negative numbers.

Example of a failure case:

RANDOM C4 = 8
RANDOM D4 = 8
=RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(SUM($C4:D4)<=6,8,14-SUM($C4:D4)))
=RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(16<=6,8,14-16))
=RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(16<=6,8,-2))
=RANDBETWEEN(0, -2)
-> FAILS DUE TO NEGATIVE #

Comment: I think I found where the issue was for this. Using 0-8 causes issues. We should instead use 0-7.

I used the following equations to prevent the negative/failure to get a RANDBETWEEN:

(MONDAY) C4: =RANDBETWEEN(0,7)
(TUESDAY) D4: =RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(SUM($C4:C4)<=6,7,14-SUM($C4:C4)))
(WEDNESDAY) E4: =RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(SUM($C4:D4)<=6,7,14-SUM($C4:D4))) 
(THURSDAY) F4: =RANDBETWEEN(0, IF(SUM($C4:E4)<=6,7,14-SUM($C4:E4)))
(FRIDAY) G4: =15-SUM(C4:F4)

Comment: Actually, if cell C4 = 8, cell D4 should never be able to be 8 as well, as the formula would see that the sum of `C4:D4` is not `<=6`. In that case, it should use the range of `14 - 8`, or `0 to 6`. Does that help at all?

Comment: OH! Yes I understand now. Retested it with that understanding and it now coming out correctly. Appreciate your time and explanation on this.

Comment: Great, I'm so glad! Absolutely :)

Answer (score 1):

While majorly overcomplicated given the other answer provided, I did go in and create a script for this.

Here is the code:

```js
function setSame() {
  console.log('Start check');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetMaster = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var sortRange = sheetMaster.getRange('B3:E3');
  var forms = ['=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)','=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)','=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)','=RANDBETWEEN(0,8)'];

  sortRange.setValues([forms]);

  var mon = sheetMaster.getRange('B3').getValue();
  sortRange.getCell(1,1).setValue(mon);
  var tues = sheetMaster.getRange('C3').getValue();
  sortRange.getCell(1,2).setValue(tues);
  var wed = sheetMaster.getRange('D3').getValue();
  sortRange.getCell(1,3).setValue(wed);
  var thurs = sheetMaster.getRange('E3').getValue();
  sortRange.getCell(1,4).setValue(thurs);
  var fri = sheetMaster.getRange('F3').getValue();

  console.log('Monday: '+mon);
  console.log('Tuesday: '+tues);
  console.log('Wednesday: '+wed);
  console.log('Thursday: '+thurs);
  console.log('Friday: '+fri);

  if(fri < 1) {
    console.log("less");
    setSame();
  }
}
```

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sL-9heySP2-H1KZS2-CYSF9vYrFfL-FThPzsJkaXqxU/edit?usp=sharing)

The `setSame()` function is set up with an `onChange` trigger (Triggers > Add Trigger). The `console.log()` lines are there for debugging purposes, and are not necessary.

I am sure there are better ways to go about this with a script, but this was the quickest way I could think to solve this.